# ListView in Column generates abnormal top margin

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a simple ListView.builder in a Column, and When a run it on IOS or on Android, I have different comportments with an abnormal top marge : please watch pics.

on IOS :[Screen IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBzGm.png)

on ANDROID :[Screen ANDROID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2Ib2.png)

Here is my code :

```
return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
             // SOME HEADER WIDGETS
             ListView.builder(
                          controller: _sc,
                          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: groups.length,
                          itemBuilder: (ctx, i) { ... })]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListView` has some default padding, you can set it to `0`.

```
ListView(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  children: ...
)
```